# Examples of client side auth in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Are there any examples of client side auth for react? Similar to https://github.com/fnakstad/angular-client-side-auth

If not, what would be a good way to handle role based showing/hiding of specific UI inside react?

Comment: Are you looking for a client side auth workflow or for a way to handle different roles by showing different partis of the UI? or both?

Comment: not an authflow. just looking for a way to handle different roles to show different parts of the UI.

Answer (score 14):

You can read a blogpost I wrote exactly about this subject :). https://auth0.com/blog/2015/04/09/adding-authentication-to-your-react-flux-app/. There's an example on Github linking from the post.

Let me know if you find it useful.

Cheers

Comment: Thanks for this. I ended up creating a mixin that I include on components where it's needed. The mixin just hides or shows an HTML element with CSS.

The core of the mixin is this method:

`requires: function(permission) {
 if(this.profile.permissions.indexOf(permission) === -1) {
  return "hidden";
 }
 else return "visible";
}`

and then I just do something like `<div className={this.requires("my-account") + " otherClassName"}>restricted content</div>`

Comment: That's cool. However, mixins are no deprecated since v.13. You should use a Composable aproach now @Eric

Comment: @mgonto I believe they reverted that decision and mixins are back in. See e.g. [1.0 - Navigation mixin](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/v1.0.0/CHANGES.md#navigation-mixin). They say that "If you were using the `Navigation` mixin, use the `History` mixin instead." Note that they are still recommending to use a mixin here.

Answer (score 10):

You should take a look at the [Stormpath React SDK](https://github.com/stormpath/stormpath-sdk-react) and its [example application](https://github.com/stormpath/stormpath-express-react-example).

Basically, with [Stormpath](https://www.stormpath.com/) and its SDK you can easily add user authentication features such as sign up, login and reset password, to your app.

It's pretty cool since the SDK integrates with React Router, adding auth to your app is very straight-forward:

```
<Router history={createBrowserHistory()}>
  <Route path='/' component={MasterPage}>
    <LoginRoute path='/login' component={LoginPage} />
    <LogoutRoute path='/logout' />
    <Route path='/register' component={RegistrationPage} />
    <AuthenticatedRoute path='/profile' component={ProfilePage} />
  </Route>
</Router>
```

Yeah, that's basically it. You just use [`AuthenticatedRoute`](https://github.com/stormpath/stormpath-sdk-react/blob/master/docs/api.md#authenticatedroute) on the pages that you want to protect.

Then on the `LoginPage` and `RegistrationPage` all you need to do is add the SDK components [`LoginForm`](https://github.com/stormpath/stormpath-sdk-react/blob/master/docs/api.md#loginform) and [`RegistrationForm`](https://github.com/stormpath/stormpath-sdk-react/blob/master/docs/api.md#registrationform) respectively. And then you have a place where your users will be able to sign up and login.

Want them to logout? Just use the SDK component [`LogoutLink`](https://github.com/stormpath/stormpath-sdk-react/blob/master/docs/api.md#logoutlink).

```
<LogoutLink />
```

And within your pages, if you want to hide/show content based if a user is authenticated or not, you can just use the SDK components [`Authenticated`](https://github.com/stormpath/stormpath-sdk-react/blob/master/docs/api.md#authenticated) and [`NotAuthenticated`](https://github.com/stormpath/stormpath-sdk-react/blob/master/docs/api.md#notauthenticated).

```
<Authenticated>
  I'm authenticated. So show this!
</Authenticated>
```

Soon it will also be possible to specify groups (roles) to the [`Authenticated`](https://github.com/stormpath/stormpath-sdk-react/blob/master/docs/api.md#authenticated) component. So you can specify that you'll only show a part of a component if it is authenticated in a certain group. E.g.

```
<Authenticated inGroup='administrators'>
  I'm an administrator \o/
</Authenticated>
```

It's that simple :)

If this sounds cool I can recommend that you take a look at the blog post that I wrote. It will take you through building a React application with these user management features:

https://stormpath.com/blog/build-a-react-app-with-user-authentication/

**Disclaimer:** I built the SDK and I work for Stormpath :)

Comment: Hi Robin, 
Thanks for the example, really helpful.
However I'm getting an error here when trying to adapt with my existing `code:  bundle.js:33050 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'dispatch' of null `

method:
`_createClass(UserActions, [{
     key: 'login',
     value: function login(options, callback) {
       this.context.getDispatcher().dispatch({
         actionType: _UserConstants2.default.USER_LOGIN,
         options: options,
         callback: callback
       });
     }
   }
`
Problem seems to be on this.context.getDispatcher(), any idea what may be the problem ?
Thanks

Comment: Hey Thomas!

Awesome to see that you're trying it out. My guess is that [`ReactStormpath.init();`](https://github.com/stormpath/stormpath-sdk-react/blob/master/docs/api.md#initialization) isn't being run properly. If you want you can send me an email at `robin [at] stormpath [dot] com` and I'll help you out :)
 
Cheers!

Comment: How do you load a profile object with user data? I mean pass it a client from a server?

Answer (score 7):

Here is a good auth flow example inside React-Router documentation : https://github.com/rackt/react-router/tree/master/examples/auth-flow

Comment: That's a really great flow for authentication, but doesn't provide authorization for showing/hiding UI elements based on a users role.

Comment: I just wrote an article on role-based auth w react. Maybe it'll help. http://blog.littleblimp.com/post/109540707808/role-based-authorization-with-react-js